# WSO2 Api Manager 3.0 Data Mapper does not work

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed wso2 Api Manager 3.0 on my windows by downloading the binaries.

I wonder if the datamapper does work in the v3.0 of the Api Manager.

it does not work in my case.

I am using OOTB sequences, but unfortunately unable to actually save it:

The logs are saying that the XML sequence are not found for the datamapper, regarding the apache-synapse configuration.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1.)Downlaod AM3.0 Binaries and install in windows machine

2.)Open publisher and create a dummy api and in request mediator select the json_to_xml or any ootb sequences. and click on save button.

SAME FLOW WORK PERFECTLY FINE IN 2.6

Please find the errror log file attached.

Please find the server logs:

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Issue is in accessing the Registry[2019-11-18 17:41:43,883] ERROR - APIUtil Issue is in accessing the Registry
[2019-11-18 17:41:43,900] ERROR - APIMappingUtil Error occurred while getting the uuid of the mediation sequence
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Issue is in accessing the Registry
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getMediationPolicyAttributes_aroundBody322(APIUtil.java:5438) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getMediationPolicyAttributes(APIUtil.java:5373) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences\in
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.get(MountHandler.java:449) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.get(HandlerManager.java:2446) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]

Comment: Could you please attach the full error log?

Comment: Looks like a bug related to path. `/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences\in`

Comment: @Menaka: PLease find the logs attached i tried in multiple time am getting the same can you please let me know if its working for you.

you can reproduce this issue by downloading latest binaries 3.0 and select any of the mediator nd click save

Comment: @Bee are you facing the same issue ??

for me am3.0 is giving this issue.
am2.6 works perfectly fine.

Comment: any update guys??

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. It is confirmed from wso2 its a bug.

https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/6847